# How to autofill flex input by using JavaScript without flashvars?

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, autofill

I have flex application (swf file). Does anyone one know how to autofill flex textInput from JavaScript without using flashVars? It must work in FireFox and IE.

Comment: Have a look at [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Comment: No, It won't work in my case. I have just swf file, without sourcecode.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it can't be done.

Comment: Really? I'm not going to give up? Who else thinks that it's impossibly.

Comment: Weel, you _could_ decompile, add the necessary code and recompile. But you're in for a trip then.

Comment: Is it a swf file that actually works with flashvars?

Comment: Yeah, it works with flashvars, but there is not logic about textInput.

Comment: You need that logic AND ExternalInterface, I see no other solution.

Comment: Does the SWF load any external SWFs or images?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `wrapper.swf` and load `main.swf` into it.

`MyApp.mxml` - Flex project application file

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:HGroup id="hGroup" width="100%" height="100%" 
        horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:TextInput id="textInput" text=""/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```

`Wrapper.as` - ActionScript project application file

```
package
{
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;

import mx.core.mx_internal;

use namespace mx_internal;

public class Wrapper extends Sprite
{

    private var loader:Loader;

    private var application:Object;

    public function Wrapper()
    {
        loader = new Loader();
        addChild(loader);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, loader_initHandler);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("MyApp.swf"), 
            new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));
    }

    private function loader_initHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    }

    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        try
        {
            application = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition(
                "mx.core.FlexGlobals").topLevelApplication;
        }
        catch (error:*)
        {
            return; // app is not ready yet
        }
        if (!application)
            return;

        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        if (application.initialized)
            injectText();
        else
            application.addEventListener("creationComplete", application_creationCompleteHandler);
    }

    private function injectText():void
    {
        var textInput:Object = application.getElementAt(0).getElementAt(0);
        if (textInput)
            textInput.text = "Custom value";
    }

    private function application_creationCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        injectText();
    }

}
}
```

[image: Result]

Finally, you can add any logic in wrapper including `ExternalInterface.addCallback`.

Comment: Now there's a creative solution. +1

Comment: Thanks, but it's not my way. So I realised that my problem can't be sorted out.